Are there better methods of clearing 'named ranges' in Excel VBA
I have written a script to run from a Ribbon to clear multiple 'named' ranges from different worksheets in a workbook. It works fine but is clumsy and I tried to use a Union query and also an Array of Sheets but ran into problems with syntax and execution. My code is:
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim source1 As Range
Dim source2 As Range
Dim source3 As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set ws = Worksheets("Estate Data Management Team")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("GEMS Business Analysts")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("GEMS Delivery Testers")

Set source1 = ws.Range("ClearEDMT")
Set source2 = ws2.Range("ClearGEMSBA")
Set source3 = ws3.Range("ClearGEMSDelivery")

If MsgBox("This will clear the EDMT, GEMS-BA & GEMS-Delivery timesheets. Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
   With source1.ClearContents
        source2.ClearContents
        source3.ClearContents
   End With
End If

I'm now looking for a more efficient solution to this code so I am welcome to some ideas I can pursue.

Are you trying to clear all named ranges or just selected ones?

What do you mean by I tried to use a Union query and also an Array of Sheets? I cannot see such an attempt. Then, clearing ranges loos like a little foggy concept... Looking to the code, you only need to clear contents of the respective ranges. Is this understanding correct? Then, **you can create a union Range (I do not understand what a union query would mean...) only on the same sheet. And in order to use a sheets array you should place their name in the array, not the object themselves.

I would keep it simple.
With ThisWorkbook
    .Worksheets("Estate Data Management Team").Range("ClearEDMT").ClearContents
    .Worksheets("GEMS Business Analysts").Range("ClearGEMSBA").ClearContents
    .Worksheets("GEMS Delivery Testers").Range("ClearGEMSDelivery").ClearContents
End With

Note that in your code, you defined a workbook variable wb but you are not using it. Therefore, your code will not work when ThisWorkbook is not the Active Workbook.
Union btw. will not work at all as you cannot Union ranges from different sheets.

I know now that a Union query doesn't work across multiple sheets. I should have realised that.

This is simply a tidier way to clear those 3 ranges:
Sub clear_named_ranges()
    
    With ThisWorkbook
    
    For Each named_range In Array( _
        .Worksheets("Estate Data Management Team").Range("ClearEDMT"), _
        .Worksheets("GEMS Business Analysts").Range("ClearGEMSBA"), _
        .Worksheets("GEMS Delivery Testers").Range("ClearGEMSDelivery"))
        named_range.ClearContents
    Next
    
    End With

End Sub


Be careful, both variants will fail if ThisWorkbook is not the active workbook.

Good point, I'll fix.

For completeness' sake:
With ThisWorkbook
    .Names("ClearEDMT").RefersToRange.ClearContents
    .Names("ClearGEMSBA").RefersToRange.ClearContents
    .Names("ClearGEMSDelivery").RefersToRange.ClearContents
End With

This also fixes the issue that renaming a worksheet will cause the other examples to fail.

If you want to clear all named ranges in a workbook, you can just loop thru them. If you wanted some of them to be preserved, you can add additional conditions to the IF statement checking for their names.
Sub ClearAllNamedRanges()
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = nm.RefersToRange
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.ClearContents
        End If
    Next nm
    
    MsgBox "All named ranges cleared."
End Sub


To clear the contents of all the named ranges of thisWorkbook :
Sub ClearAllNamedRanges()
Dim x
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each x In ThisWorkbook.Names
      Application.Evaluate(x.RefersTo).ClearContents
   Next
   MsgBox "All named ranges cleared."
End Sub

To clear only some named ranges of thisWorkbook :
Sub ClearSomeNamedRanges()
Dim x
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each x In Array("range1Name", "range2Name")
     Application.Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names(x).RefersTo).ClearContents
   Next
   MsgBox "All named ranges cleared."
End Sub

